# Create an object using Expression Trees without generic arguments

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, expression-trees

I have a class that is a bit like the following

```
public class SpecialList<T> : List<T>
{
    public SingleOrList() { }
    public SingleOrList(IEnumerable<T> list) : base(list) {}
    ...
}
```

When converting it from JSON, it can be turned into this special list as either a single object, or an array of that object in the following manner.

```cs
...

public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var token = JToken.Load(reader);

    if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        var originalList = token.ToObject(objectType.BaseType, serializer);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, originalList);
    }

    var list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
    var genericType = objectType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
    var single = token.ToObject(genericType, serializer);

    list.Add(single);

    return list;
}
```

Ignoring the fact of whether or not this is a good idea for the moment, I was interested in whether you could use / how you would use complied expression trees here instead of `Activator.CreateInstance` to create the classes.

Most of the examples I've seen use generics which is not possible for me here as I don't know up front the generic type, e.g.

```
public static Func<T> Instance = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(Expression.New(typeof(T))).Compile();
```

---

Based on canton7's comment, where `TypeCreators` is some form of cache:

```
private static IList CreateForType(Type objectType)
{
    if (TypeCreators.TryGetValue(objectType, out var func))
    {
        return func();
    }

    var newFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<IList>>(Expression.New(objectType)).Compile();
    TypeCreators.TryAdd(objectType, newFunc);
    return newFunc();
}
```

Comment: Sure, `Expression.Lambda<Func<IList>>(Expression.New(objectType)).Compile()` (you might need to throw an `Expression.Convert(..., typeof(IList))` in there). That will probably be slower than `Activator.CreateInstance` however. If you cache the compiled delegate for each `objectType`, *then* you might be able to measure a small speed gain

Comment: Thanks @canton7, that does look to be what I'm after. I've updated my post with what I think you were saying.

I guess I'd need either a separate function or one that knows which constructor to call if I wanted to do it for scenarios where there are multiple constructors like in my example.

Wasn't so worried about speed, more just interested in how you would do it.

Comment: That depends entirely on how you decide which constructor to call, I guess. It gets a more more tricky when you're passing *in* a `T`: presumably you'll have to pass in an `IEnumerable<object>`, and then cast each element to a `T` inside the expression (or give `SpecialList` a constructor which takes an `IEnumerable<object>`)